# How to make spikes with displacement

Tags: displacement, procedural

[image]

I'm trying to make this shapes in the image, is there a way to make the randomized spikes?
My first attempts were with hair particle system but it's not connected, so I tried with sculpting but the orientation needs to be almost perfect so it didn't work (the only randomness is the spread /density and the scale/legth). This is why I'm trying with displacement, also because I want to make many variants so I want it to be a non-destructive workflow.
If you know a way that doesn't involve displacement let me know anyway, my goal is to obtain those shapes so even if it's destructive workflow and takes longer it's ok.
Please let me know if you have any ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the action of your displacement modifier with a vertex group, to which you will assign only the vertices you want to displace.

[image]

Comment: I've been trying to find a nice way, procedurally, to select random vertices, and weight them to displace in the right way, in the geodesic geometry, (perhaps before skinning / wireframing), using the _Vertex Weight_ _Mix_ and _Edit_ modifiers... _Normal Edit_ modifier.. Nothing tidy yet :(

Comment: @josh thank you so much that woked perfectly!